# Any tools to beautify the nested NSDictionary result

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdictionary

Is there any tools, including online service and macOs app, to beautify the nested `NSDictionary` result like this?

```
   { 
        id = 1;
        testName = my name;
        createDate = 20021023;
        likeNumber = 0;
        statusList = ({
                appleId = 1;
                orangeName = 81;
                itsStatus = YES;
        });
        text = test;
        type = Text;
   },
```

I mean collapse(close and open) the tree nodes easily.

Currently ,there are many online tools for this purpose when it comes to `JSON` like [jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com).

Comment: is your dictionary JSONafiable? cause you could just print it as JSON first then use one of the other tools.. ?

Comment: By printing you mean? Or by indenting in code?

Comment: @Larme none of them, see https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @Fonix I think its the only solution, yes

Comment: @SoheilNovinfard What I meant is: If you do in your code `NSDict *@{@"key":@(1), @[@{@"Key2:&(3)}]...}`, there could be some plug in for XCode that indent it. Now. The result string you gave is from a "print"/NSLog, so what's the purpose ? Using a "beautify" `description` of NSDictionary ? Doing only logs ?

Comment: @Larme I need a tree view with close and open nodes feature (not text only). In this way, I could hide each node to focus on the desired section each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Fonix mentioned, the best way to convert `NSDictionary` to `JSON` and then use `JSON` tools for this purpose:

```
+(NSString *)dictionaryToJson:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                         error:&error];

    NSString *jsonString;
    if (! jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
        jsonString = [error localizedDescription];
    } else {
        jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
    return jsonString;
}
```